# Customize URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, friendly-url

I have a blog that use authentication and where users are able to create posts my post is generated via scaffold and want that users when want to edit a posts they will redirected to something like this localhost:3000/posts/jack-stone/the-first-post/edit instead of localhost:3000/posts/the-first-post/edit (jack-stone is the user full name and the-first-post is the post title (I'm using FriendlyId gem for this)) How can i achieve this? my actual routes for posts  is `resources :posts`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to configure using `match` statement with a pattern.

```
match '/posts/:user_full_name/:post_title/edit', :to => "posts#edit", :via => 'get'
```

Params available in `posts#edit` will then be `params[:user_full_name]` and `params[:post_title]`.

Further reading: [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/match)